# Palantir Foundry: How can I specify which namespace a project gets created to in the Foundry UI?

Tags: palantir-foundry

How can I specify which namespace a project gets created to in the UI? And where do I do this in the Foundry platform?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project, you get a picker if you can create projects in more than one namespace.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).